# Flask app not showing the "Running on ..." statement

Tags: flask

The Flask app shows the following output:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'api'
 * Debug mode: on
```

The "* Running on " statement is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I incorporated a logger, all the api logs including this 'running on' were being logged and not visible on the terminal.